# Найти строку с максимальным значением в каждой группе (после группировки)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть exel таблица, в ней в одном столбце перечислен список городов, в другом годов, в третьем номера недель, в четвертом количество человек и ещё несколько столбцов которые можно опустить. 
Нужно найти неделю, при которой wd_total является максимальной а wda_total имеет значение Э, то есть нужно выбирать максимальные значения из Э, только сделать нужно для городов и годов отдельно. Например для Архангельска 1990г неделя 4, для Архангельска 1991г неделя 9 итд.
Таблицу я подгружаю, а дальше не могу сообразить. Помогите пожалуйста.
https://yadi.sk/i/dkGsdWKdH7NC0w

Comment: можете выложить ваш Excel файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник? А еще лучше будет если вы приведете небольшой пример входных данных (в виде текста или CSV, чтобы можно было скопировать) и результат, который вы хотите получить прямо в вопросе

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста как вы хотите считать максимум - за год (сумма для всех недель года) для каждого города или за год и неделю для каждого города?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/obDkkeDtW1W-0Q

Comment: Можете ответить на вопрос о группировке?

Comment: В вашем файле данные для единственного города и за один год - в результате вы получите одну строку на выходе... Это неудачный пример входных данных...

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
  town_name  cld_year  week_number  wd_total
0       aaa      1990            1        10
1       aaa      1990            3        19
2       aaa      1990            6        10
3       aaa      1991           10        21
4       aaa      1991           33        19
5       bbb      1990            5        10
6       bbb      1990           15        10
7       bbb      1991           25        21
8       bbb      1991           35        33
```

Решение:

```
In [22]: res = (df.groupby(['town_name','cld_year'], as_index=False)
    ...:          .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1,['wd_total']))
    ...:          .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

Результат:

```
In [23]: res
Out[23]:
  town_name  cld_year  week_number  wd_total
1       aaa      1990            3        19
3       aaa      1991           10        21
5       bbb      1990            5        10
8       bbb      1991           35        33
```

---

для [данных по ссылке](https://yadi.sk/i/dkGsdWKdH7NC0w):

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\download\табл1.xlsx', na_values=['NULL'])

res = (df.groupby(['town_name','cld_year'], as_index=False)
         .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1,['wd_total']))
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

результат:

```
In [71]: res
Out[71]:
         town_name  cld_year  week_number  wd_total wda_total  qty_total    ...     wd_7_14 wda_7_14  qty_7_14   wd_15 wda_15    qty_15
3      Архангельск      1990            4    8357.0         Э   424700.0    ...      1427.0        Э   48865.0  4637.0      Э  333581.0
60     Архангельск      1991            9   10206.0         Э   427600.0    ...      3239.0        Э   49377.0  4621.0      Э  337173.0
107    Архангельск      1992            4    9067.0         Э   428200.0    ...      2696.0        Э   49168.0  3886.0      Э  339615.0
162    Архангельск      1993            7    6578.0         Э   421000.0    ...      1620.0        Э   49188.0  3434.0      Э  334924.0
214    Архангельск      1994            7    8026.0         Э   417000.0    ...      1858.0        Э   49002.0  4600.0      Э  334077.0
312    Архангельск      1995           53    9975.0       NaN   414700.0    ...      2783.0      NaN   50194.0  5460.0    NaN  333036.0
313    Архангельск      1996            1    5229.0         Э   382600.0    ...      1127.0        Э   51160.0  2822.0      Э  302290.0
369    Архангельск      1997            5    6813.0         Э   379900.0    ...      2373.0        Э   51200.0  3386.0      Э  301768.0
428    Архангельск      1998           12    8429.0         Э   372000.0    ...      3242.0        Э   50116.0  3743.0      Э  296618.0
476    Архангельск      1999            8   11964.0         Э   372500.0    ...      2934.0        Э   48512.0  7476.0      Э  299877.0
...            ...       ...          ...       ...       ...        ...    ...         ...      ...       ...     ...    ...       ...
68483       Якутск      2007           13    1876.0       NaN   260350.0    ...       246.0      NaN   30395.0   414.0    NaN  202848.0
68571       Якутск      2008           49    2139.0       NaN   260350.0    ...       330.0      NaN   30395.0   418.0    NaN  202848.0
68619       Якутск      2009           45   11807.0         Э   276245.0    ...      2834.0        Э   30702.0  3887.0      Э  216846.0
68675       Якутск      2010           49    3371.0       NaN   287954.0    ...       660.0        Э   30843.0   521.0    NaN  224807.0
68686       Якутск      2011            8    4116.0         Э   287954.0    ...       380.0      NaN   30843.0  1654.0      Э  224807.0
68782       Якутск      2012           52    3967.0       NaN   295664.0    ...       950.0      NaN   31244.0   396.0    NaN  232277.0
68799       Якутск      2013           16    3409.0         Э   312596.0    ...       523.0        Э   29467.0   343.0    NaN  249632.0
68885       Якутск      2014           50    3783.0       NaN   312596.0    ...       767.0      NaN   29467.0   479.0    NaN  249632.0
68894       Якутск      2015            7    3995.0         Э   325241.0    ...       795.0        Э   31414.0   481.0    NaN  257818.0
68944       Якутск      2016            5    6424.0         Э   325241.0    ...       719.0        Э   31414.0  1966.0      Э  257818.0

[1212 rows x 18 columns]
```

Comment: @Анна, вы пробовали данное решение на ваших данных?

Comment: @Анна, для того, чтобы что-нибудь посчитать нужно точно понимать задачу. Без небольшого примера входных и выходных данных трудно понять что и как вы хотите получить на выходе. Советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: а можно ли сделать так, чтобы  порядковый номер недели считался не от начала года, а от появления первой буквы Э в массиве данных. то есть например для Архангельска 1990г это неделя 4, а для Архангельска 1991г неделя 3, так как из всех Э за этот период, максимальное значение приходится на третью Э.

Comment: @Анна, я думаю лучше будет открыть новый SO вопрос и перенести все уточнения из комментариев к этому вопросу в тело нового вопроса...